# Why is it easier to program games in Pygames and not Python alone?

Tags: python, pygame

Im new to Python and I am getting to grips with it.

**I have a question:** why is Python it self not used to develop games? I can see why Pygame games is used, due to ease of loading images on to the screen for example. If I was to develop a game in Python, would it mean I would have to manually display images to the screen? Or do Python also provide these set of libraries?

For example in Pygame you would have:

> pygame.image.load("image.jpg").convert()

to load an image to the screen.

If I was to do this in python, would I have to manually load images? Read from a file then display? Is this all done in the underlining code for Pygame?

Comment: That's what libraries **do**: make tedious jobs easier by encapsulation.

Comment: " why is Python it self not used to develop games? " . It IS "Python itself". PyGames is not a different language, it's a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as you are progressing more into game development you'll find out that you need more and more things in order to do what you have in mind. What pygame and all these dev kits do, is that they've already done the work for you.

If you are going to create a serious game,you'll need collision modules, animation modules, sprite loading modules, maybe music and video, controls and more.

Without pygame you'll have to create all of them from scratch :P.

I don't know about the inners of Pygame and to be honest i haven't used it, but i can assure you from my experience in game development that its a real PAIN to make anything from scratch so eventually you'll need something as a base for your game. Thats why there are so many game engines around ;)

Unless you are a python prodigy or something :P

Comment: Thanks Greg! :) +1 also because its your first post:)